# Flex List : different appearence to first item

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

I am creating a mobile application showing a news list with Flex.

Each news has a title and a picture, so I am using a list with an iconItemRenderer to display results. It seems that itemRenderers always give the same appearence to all items.

But I'd like to give a different appearence to the first item, with a full width picture and a bigger title. I don't know how to do that.

Any idea ?

Comment: What about creating your custom renderer?

Comment: You mean a custom itemRenderer class in actionscript ? I am trying : I followed this tutorial [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOpsDZaQrOI), but i don't see where you can 'catch' the first item

Comment: You should be able to use an itemRendererFunction to use a different renderer for the first item than the rest of them.

Comment: You're right Flextras, this will do the job.
More info here : [link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/03/19/using-a-custom-item-renderer-function-with-the-fxlist-control-in-flex-gumbo/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom component and override some basic method. So, i've try to do this, but faced some problems. May be that problem not fixed in flex 3 (i've using flex 3 :-) ).
So, in spite this i have found solution.

```
import mx.controls.List;
import mx.core.IFactory;

public class ListEx extends List{

    public function ListEx(){
        super();
    }

    public var item1stRenderer:IFactory;
    public var item1stCount:int=1;
    private static var _first:int = 0;

    override public function getItemRendererFactory(data:Object):IFactory{
        if(_first<=item1stCount && item1stRenderer != null && data != null){
            return item1stRenderer;
        }else{
            return super.getItemRendererFactory(data);
        }
    }

    override public function get itemRenderer():IFactory{
        if(_first<=item1stCount && item1stRenderer != null){
            _first++;
            return item1stRenderer;
        }else{
            return super.itemRenderer;
        }           
    }       
}
```

And let's test it!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" height="100%" width="100%" xmlns:local="*">

    <mx:Model id="mystates">
        <states>
            <state label="Alabama" data="AL"/>
            <state label="Alaska" data="AK"/>
            <state label="Arizona" data="AZ"/>
            <state label="Arkansas" data="AR"/>
            <state label="California" data="CA"/>
            <state label="Colorado" data="CO"/>
            <state label="Connecticut" data="CT"/>
        </states>
    </mx:Model>

    <local:ListEx itemRenderer="mx.controls.TextInput" id="g_list" dataProvider="{mystates.state}" width="100%">
        <local:item1stRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:Label color="blue"/>
            </mx:Component>
        </local:item1stRenderer>
    </local:ListEx>

</mx:Application>
```

Hope, i can help you.

PS: sorry for my english, i'm russian speaking :)

Comment: as you can see, two method must be overrided, may be there is bug

Comment: One more! You can set another item renderer for first N elements, not only one